# xamarin Binding To List

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and C#, so forgive me if my code is crap.

So essentially I'm trying to create a simple page that displays a list of course names, and allows a button to insert or remove items from the list within the view.

As of now the program builds and runs but the view does not display the contents of the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the view:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Label Text= "My Courses" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Frame>

        <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <ListView x:Name="CourseList" ItemsSource="{Binding GetCourseList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>

                            <Button FontSize="14" Text="X" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        </Frame>

        <Button Text="+" FontSize="20" TextColor="Green" BackgroundColor="Silver"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center"
               Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                />
    </Grid>
```

Here's the View.cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainPageViewModel vm;                               

    public MainPage()
    {
        vm = new MainPageViewModel();                  

        vm.AddCourse();

        BindingContext = vm;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Here's the View Model:

```
class MainPageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses;


    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Courses = new List<Course>();
    }


    public List<Course> GetCourseList()
    {
        return Courses;
    }

    public void AddCourse()
    {
        Course NewCourse = new Course();
        NewCourse.Name = "New Course Added";

        Courses.Add(NewCourse);
    }

}
```

Finally, Here's my Model:

```
    public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

So I have been able to display a list using this code but I do not believe this will allow me to add or delete from the list and update the view via button click (Correct me if I'm wrong).

```
public List<Course> Courses{
    get{
       return new List<Course>(){
           new Course(){Name = "Added a course"}
          };
       }
```

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of list. Maybe you need to run it as a property aswell. Never bound a method, only properties, so don't know if you can do that. The reason for using Observable is that it will tell the view, when it receives new items and update the view.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll look that up now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found my error and solution.

```
    public List<Course> Courses{
get{
   return new List<Course>(){
       new Course(){Name = "Added a course"}
      };
   }
```

Because Courses is "read only" and now being bound to the view I created a member variable List VMCourse to hold the actually list of objects and am using Courses to be bounded to and read into the view.

It appears to work, but I still need to test it with button features for adding and deleting from the list. Does this look like a decent solution to you guys?

Thanks in advance!

```
class MainPageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Course> VMCourse;


    //This is now bound to the view's listview
    public List<Course> Courses {
        get
        {
            return VMCourse;
        }
    }


    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        VMCourse = new List<Course>();
    }

    public void AddCourse()
    {
        Course NewCourse = new Course();
        NewCourse.Name = "New Course Added";

        VMCourse.Add(NewCourse);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a list to a method. You should use binding with properties. So to fix this you only need to change

```
public List<Course> GetCourseList()
{
    return Courses;
}
```

To

```
public List<Course> GetCourseList
{
    get { return Courses; }
}
```

But, as it's mentioned in the comments not any property is suitable to be used with binding unless you know what you are doing so search about binding.